# Optimizing sums from an array of values with specific conditions?

Tags: arrays, sum, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to figure out how I would go about finding the highest sum from an array of values while following specific conditions. Specifically, I have a 6xN array, and I want to take two values from each column of the array (for 12 total) such that the sum is maximized. Each row can only be used once. If there's a method that doesn't involve brute-forcing and heavy permutation and can be simply implemented in Excel (that's where I'm working), that would be ideal.

Previously I've just been eyeballing which values would be ideal for a sum and guesstimating based off that. I've done some brainstorming and couldn't come up with anything beyond brute-forcing, definitely nothing simple enough to work in Excel without some kind of external script.

If this is a pipe dream, that's fine too. Was just curious if there was a simple way to do it. Attached is an example of an array I'd be working with (with my guesstimated values outlined)

[image: Example array of values]

Comment: Have you read about Excel Solver?

Answer (score 0):

There are a family of nice algorithms for this problem.

Let’s suppose first that you want to select one item from each column and at most one item from each row, and you want to maximize the sum of the items you pick. This is called the ***assignment problem*** (or ***maximum-weight bipartite matching***) and there are numerous polynomial-time exact algorithms for it. The most famous is the ***Hungarian algorithm***, which is relatively straightforward to code up.

In your case, you want to pick at most *two* items from each column. But that’s easy to address - you can just duplicate each column and now your problem is identical to the assignment problem and the above algorithms will work.

Answer (score 0):

One typical approach to this is linear programming. Linear programming is available in Excel via the Solver feature, but I don't have Excel so I demonstrate in Python.

The idea is to frame the problem as a series of matrix multiplications:

- your assignments `x` are a vector of 0 or 1 values to be determined by the solver;
- `c` is a flattened version of the values from your spreadsheet above that, when multiplied by `x` via dot product, is minimized;
- `A` is a matrix that, when multiplied by your assignments, produces a column vector of values to which constraint lower and upper bounds are compared.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import milp

# Load from a CSV-formatted file (Excel is also possible but less efficient)
values = np.loadtxt('76749339.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=int)
m, n = values.shape

# Identity matrix for row uniqueness constraint
row_identity = np.broadcast_to(
    np.identity(m)[:, :, np.newaxis],  # mm1
    (m, m, n),
).reshape((m, m*n))

# Identity matrix for column count constraint
col_identity = np.broadcast_to(
    np.identity(n)[:, np.newaxis, :],  # n1n
    (n, m, n),
).reshape(n, m*n)

# Combined identity matrices for constraints
A = np.vstack((row_identity, col_identity))

# Low constraint bounds: row counts at least zero, column counts two
b_lo = np.concatenate((
    np.zeros(shape=m),
    np.full(shape=n, fill_value=2),
))

# High constraint bounds: row counts at most one, column counts two
b_hi = np.concatenate((
    np.ones(shape=m),
    np.full(shape=n, fill_value=2),
))

# Run mixed-integer linear programming solver
result = milp(
    # "minimize positive" means "maximize negative"
    c=-values.ravel(),
    # All assignments are 0 or 1, so integers and not continuous
    integrality=np.ones(m*n),
    # All assignments are 0 or 1
    bounds=(0, 1),
    constraints=(A, b_lo, b_hi),
)
assert result.success, result.message
print(result.message)

assigned = result.x.reshape((m, n))

print('Values:')
x, y = (assigned > 0.5).T.nonzero()
print(values[y, x].reshape((n, 2)).T, end='\n\n')

print('Positions:')
print(y.reshape((n, 2)).T + 1)
```

```
Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
Values:
[[34 34 43 35 34 34]
 [27 28 41 35 36 30]]

Positions:
[[ 6 11  1 22  3  2]
 [ 9 12  5 23  7 21]]
```